# Laravel | jenssegers mongo DB. How to select from model with fields provided in $hidden?

Tags: laravel, jenssegers-mongodb

I have a model `User`.

There is a defined a hidden property.

```
protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token', 
        'user_type', 'balance', 'reputation', 'country', 'region', 'dob', 'street', 'zipPostal'
    ];
```

Mostly all this fields are should be hidden and it works, but sometimes I need to avoid this restriction and select with this data.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution in a standart `->makeVisible(['<property_name>'])` function.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json

So, it looks like:

$user = Auth::user()->makeVisible(['balance', 'reputation']);